# Constructing book cover using div and CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to use some divs and css to make a book cover like the one below(ignore the orange background) with editable titles, most the book covers I checked online don't look like this. I know am probably asking a lot but I would really appreciate any help on this.
[image]

Comment: I having tried anything yet. I don't have enough knowledge about CSS to try to do a complicated thing like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

```
<div style="width:400px; height:800px">
    <div style="display: table; width:400px; height: 100px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; background-color:blue;">
            <h4 style="color:white;text-align:center">
                <i style="color:yellow">image</i>Training book header text
            </h4>                       
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table; width:400px; height: 250px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
        <h1 style="text-align:center">Training book body text</h1>
        </div></div>
<div style="display: table; width:400px; height: 100px;">
        <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; background-color:grey;">
            <h4 style="color:white;text-align:center">
                Training book footer text<i style="color:yellow; float:right">image</i>
            </h4>                       
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/457567wy/

Comment: This is good, but it does not look like the picture. It is not rotated at an angle or has a shadow...

Comment: It is all possible. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_box-shadow and http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transform_rotate

Comment: If I was of help please vote and select as answer, thank you.